# Add COUNT in Javascript alert box

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

This page is where user will select the semester and program, then alert box will prompted on the selected program as per the image below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/takgK.png)

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#prg").change(function(){
 var selectedcount = $('#prg option:selected').data('count'); 

alert ("The next intake for " +selectedcount + " will have    "    + "students"); 
}); </script>
```

**Body**

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Select Current Semester:</label>
              <select name="semester" class="form-control">
                  <option value="">--- Select Current Semester ---</option>

                  <?php
                    require('../setting/config.php');
                      $query = "SELECT DISTINCT semester FROM marketing_data ORDER BY semester DESC"; 
                      $do = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do)){
                          echo '<option value="'.$row['student_matric'].'">'.$row['semester'].'</option>';
                      }
                  ?>
              </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Select Programme:</label>
              <select id="prg" name="prg" class="form-control">
                <option value="">--- Select Programme ---</option>

                  <?php
                      $query2 = "SELECT student_prg, COUNT(student_prg) as count FROM marketing_data GROUP BY student_prg ORDER BY student_prg DESC"; 
                      $do = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do)){
                          echo '<option value="'.$row['student_matric'].' data-count="'.$row['count'].'">'.$row['student_prg'].'</option>';
                      }
                ?>
              </select>
```

I wants the alert box to add on the number of students as well. Eg: *The next intake for Bachelor of Multimedia Industry (Hons) will have ***36*** students*

Could you assist on where and how to add the count query so that it will be shown in the alert box as I mentioned.

**Database**

```
mysql> describe marketing_data;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------+
| Field         | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------+
| student_matric| varchar(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| student_prg   | text unsigned        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| semester      | varchar(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| intake_year   | int(10)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| student_city  | text                 | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city_lat      | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city_long     | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| student_state | text                 | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state_code    | varchar(100)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the counts for each record with a query like this:

```
SELECT student_prg, COUNT(student_prg) as count FROM marketing_data GROUP BY student_prg ORDER BY student_prg DESC
```

Your results will now have a count of the number of each `student_prg` values.

Then I would probably add the count as a data attribute of the options that you're writing:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['student_prg'].' data-count="'.$row['count'].'">'.$row['student_prg'].'</option>';
```

Then you can select the value from the newly selected option.

Comment: I've edited the code as above, @Alec Sanger .. Do you mean in that way? But the alert box doesn't prompt now at all... Please assist to check..

Comment: ```var selectedcount = $('#prg option:selected').data('count');```, then just add `selectedcount` to your alert.

Comment: Sounds like you need to make sure that your javascript code is actually loading correctly. Put some `console.log('test');` statements in the `ready` and in the `.change` functions and make sure that you see those in your console.

Comment: Actually... are you saying that it's not popping up with the alert box at all now?

Comment: Yes @Alec Sanger ... It is not popping up at all

Comment: It might be because the echo was using the wrong row name. I just updated it to use `student_prg`. If that's the right row name that you want, then it should work. Give it another shot.

Comment: Sorry, dude. I can’t run this whole thing locally because I don’t have a PHP server up and don’t have the same data as you. Use your critical thinking skills and figure out what part is failing. Check the option HTML that’s being output and see if it’s spitting out the proper count value, check your $row variable and see if it contains what you expect, add some console.log and echo statements to print debug information. What I provided should get you 99% of the way there.

Comment: Thank you, @Alec Sanger .... I've tried changed many times, but still couldn't..

Comment: Anyone else could assist on this?